# React Hooks passing functions as props within objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am (still, sadly) trying to convert the [React + Material UI + Firebase](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase) template (found in the Material UI docs) using hooks. Currently, within the components folder within src, the [App.js](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase/blob/master/src/components/App/App.js) file shows that the various dialogs (i.e. modals) are first passed into a DialogHost Component, which in turn renders out to the screen the various dialogs depending on what the user clicks and toggles (e.g. sign in to give the sign in dialog, sign up to give sign up) or the user's authentication status (e.g. profile to give a profile dialog or settings to give a settings dialog).

Right now, without the DialogHost, I have my sign up and sign in Dialog's rendering in App.js like this (which was how it was done in the template React + Material UI + Firebase repo before June 26th).

```
       {/* SignUpDialog */}
        <Hidden only='xs'>
          <SignUpDialog
            open={signUpDialog}
            onClose={() => setSignUpDialog(false)}
          />
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden only={['sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl']}>
          <SignUpDialog
            fullScreen
            open={signUpDialog}
            onClose={() => setSignUpDialog(false)}
          />
        </Hidden>

        {/* SignInDialog */}
        <Hidden only='xs'>
          <SignInDialog
            open={signInDialog}
            onClose={() => setSignInDialog(false)}
          />
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden only={['sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl']}>
          <SignInDialog
            fullScreen
            open={signInDialog}
            onClose={() => setSignInDialog(false)}
          />
        </Hidden>
```

My trouble is is when I replace this code above in my [App.js](http://in-CS506/client/blob/master/src/App.js) with a single DialogHost component... I can pass the open boolean variable, which is toggled to true when the user clicks on the navbar. However, I am having trouble passing the onClose props, which allows the dialog to be exited if the user clicks a cancel button... Ultimately, a simplified version is looking like this

**App.js**

```
const [signUpDialog, setSignUpDialog] = useState(false)
const [signInDialog, setSignInDialog] = useState(false)
```

.
.
.

```
     <DialogHost
          signedIn={signedIn}
          dialogs={
            {
              signUpDialog: {
                dialogProps: {
                  open: signUpDialog,

                  onClose: () => setSignUpDialog(false) //HERE IS WHERE I AM UNSURE
                }
              },

              signInDialog: {
                dialogProps: {
                  open: signInDialog,

                  onClose: () => setSignInDialog(false) //AND HERE
                }
              }
            }
          }
        />
```

**Dialog.js**

```
const DialogHost = ({ signedIn, dialogs }) => {

const signUpDialog = dialogs.signUpDialog;
const signInDialog = dialogs.signInDialog;

return (
    <>
        <Hidden xsDown> //There is other hidden tags, but just not listing for simplicity 
            {!signedIn &&
                <>
                    <SignUpDialog
                        dialogProps={signUpDialog.dialogProps}
                    />
                    <SignInDialog
                        dialogProps={signInDialog.dialogProps}
                    />
                </>
            }
        </Hidden>
```

**SignUpDialog.js**

```
const SignUpDialog = ({ dialogProps }) => {
return (
        <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth="md" {...dialogProps}>
            <DialogTitle>
                Sign up for an account
            </DialogTitle>...
        <DialogActions><Button color='primary' onClick={dialogProps.onClose}>Cancel</Button></DialogActions>
```

Would be forever grateful if someone knew how help solve this issue I am having

Comment: can you make a sandbox snippet of your problem so I can help you out?

Comment: I got it working actually. Must've been a dumb error I caught along the way. Here is a codepen if anyone is having this problem or is interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-react-hooks-7cm6j